# Moving website to different host

Tags: web-hosting

I'm a freelancer working on a small contract. They've been with my server world for years. It's more expensive than others out there. If I was to move away from them, do I just need to update the domain then move files over to new host?

What exactly would I have to do with the domain? I believe it's with 123reg

Answer (score 2):

First, get a copy of your website saved locally.  Next, copy your site to your new web host.  Then, check that the site functions by accessing it on the new web host by it's IP address directly.  After you're comfortable that it's working as expected update your DNS records to point to your new IP.

Comment: Typically the easiest way to double check this is via a Hostfile change (point www.whatever.com to a different IP) that way if the website is programmed to require the domain name it should still function properly.  I've run into a few fun websites because someone programmed everything statically instead of dynamically.. :(

Comment: Good point. It might also be using host headers (http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm) but hopefully the site that you have doesn't.  If you're lucky you should be able to bring it up remotely by IP or locally by adding it to the host file as GruffTech mentioned.  If not, then it might take a bit more tweaking to get it moved successfully.

Comment: Moniker it does relies on the servername being set within the vhost config due to bloody query strings within includes. The servername does hosting companies always set that ? Otherwise how would they be able to host multiple sites on one server?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer upload the website to a new hosting provider and change the A records for the domain to point to the new providers ip address.

Long answer
Make sure the nameservers are set to 123-reg as well as the registration being with them. check this with a whois lookup. If not in the 123-reg control panel manage your domain, select name servers and then use default name servers. Once this is done you can edit DNS records through the 123-reg cp. You will want to set two records to point to your new providors ip address one with the prefix www and one for just the bare domain name (confusingly this is marked with an @ symbol in the 123-reg panel it's not the MX record or related to mail).

If your website relies on a database you will need to get a dump of that to import into your new hosting provider myserverworld provides a database administration page where you can export your database, your new provider will have something similar were this can be imported. If you do need to move a database you will need to update the connection string in your websites code with a new hostname and possibly password.

Answer (score 0):

What a rubbish answer, host at home, then buy your domain from us, hey, but they already have  domain name, so stop selling your domains....

You can always have a domain with one company and hosting with another, or host both together. Domain transfers can be a pain, especially when handling for a client.

123 do offer hosting, at a better rate than their sister company with Webfusion, maybe check them out.

To change the domains DNS, your client has to provide login details to the control panel, just change them under manage name servers, your host will have that information.